# Modal popup with backend call

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement that says I have to go the a backend service before showing up the modal, like when clicking on modal tab in [this](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/people/managers) example.

On stickymodaldemo.js, line 64, I tried to call the backend service and discriminate the usual then onSuccess functions, but is not working. That modal should pop up with dynamic information fetched from the backend.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code with what you want to do, but is not populating with the backend data you want.

Comment: I don't see where you call the service in provided example. Did you read about promises in AngularJS? http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: resourceAccessService.submitSearch($scope.userScope).then(function onSuccess(data){
  if (data.status == 200){
 $modal.open({ templateUrl: 'modal1.html',

and the rest of the code.

Modal1.html needs the data from the backend call, but is undefined.